# Вылетает приложение когда пытаюсь инжектить DLL

Tags: c++, dll

Я написал простой код на c++. Компилировал в DLL. При инжекте мое приложение просто вылетает. Инжектил в Assault Cube, Dota2 и другие игры.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>


DWORD WINAPI MainThread(HMODULE hModule) {

    MessageBox(0, LPCWSTR('asd'), LPCWSTR('asd'), 0);

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hModule, 0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainThread, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите, в чем проблема кода?

Перепробовал все возможное, посмотрел гайды, ничего не выходит(

Comment: `CreateThread` является небезопасной функцией для вызова в теле DllMain. В теории может все по одному месту пойти

Comment: а какой тогда использовать?